# correct static variable in android

Tags: java, android, static

i have a class:

```
public class Vars {

    public static final String NAME = "Alex";
    public static final String RANK = "COLONEL";

}
```

in my activities i do:

```
doSomething(Vars.NAME);

doSomething(Vars.RANK);
```

Is it correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Should be OK. What error are you getting?

Comment: Yes... It is fine. You can access your static variables using class name.

Comment: None errors, but in guides I frequently found more complicated solutions, with getters, setters and singletons in Application class.



If I in my Vars class have this:


public static ArrayList myList;


It can disappear when my app go to background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it should. Having all your constants in one class is usually also recommended since it makes it easier to maintain all your constants, not to mention to reduce replication of constants across classes.

Comment: also he can use static getter :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about accessing a public static variable from another class, **Yes** you are doing 100% write coding.

You can access a public static variable directly using the **`className.variableName`**